# Replace function without in built functions Java

Tags: java

probably a silly question but i've searched and searched and can't seem to find a way that to replace a substring within a string using a for loop and not built in java functions such as replace, replaceAll etc. I've tried to create my own but ended up with about 4 for loops which in the end didn't work. Any idea of how to go about creating a replace function with loops and not built in replace functions??

I've added my code that I attempted to give an idea of variables i'm using.

```
public boolean replaceString(String oldString, String newString){
        String D = "xx";
    char[] find = "BC".toCharArray();
    char[] replace ="ABCDE".toCharArray();
    String rep = new String(replace);
    String fin = new String(find);
    String E ="";
    String F = "";
    for(int counter = 0; counter<replace.length; counter++){
        if(find[counter] == replace[counter]){
            for(int j=counter+1; j<counter; counter++){
                E += rep.charAt(j);
                for(int h=j+1; h<j; h++){
                    if(find[h] == replace[h]){
                        for(int k=h+1; k<h; k++){
                            F += rep.charAt(k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    String finReplace = new String(E + D + F);
    System.out.println("REPLACE");
    System.out.println(finReplace);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why your method returns `boolean`?

Comment: Whats the use case or its just for practice?

Comment: `replaceString` should get 3 parameters, original string, search string and a replacement string

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is for assignment. So giving you pseudo code.
`

```
public static String replaceString(
final String inputString,
final String searchString,
final String newString)
{
 if ( searchString==null || searchString.equals("") ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Search string must have some content");
 }

 final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();

 int startIdx = 0;
 int idxOld = 0;
 while ((idxOld = inputString.indexOf(searchString, newString)) >= 0) {
   result.append( inputString.substring(startIdx, idxOld) );

   result.append( newString);
   startIdx = idxOld + searchString.length();
 }
 //the final chunk will go to the end of aInput
 result.append( inputString.substring(startIdx) );
 return result.toString();
```

}

Comment: It's basically for practice, the only reason I have a boolean return is so then I can implement a test on the string afterwards to determine if the replace has been successful or not.

Comment: instead you should return the replaced string and then do the comparison. You can use the method i provided.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code again. The below will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when counter is 2

```
if(find[counter] == replace[counter])
```

The following loop will never execute and j is initialized to counter+1, but the condition to run the loop is j should be less than counter

```
for(int j=counter+1; j<counter; counter++)
```

Same goes for inner loop

```
for(int h=j+1; h<j; h++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you :

```
StringBuilder replacedString = new StringBuilder();

for(int counter = 0; counter<replace.length; counter++){
    boolean charFound = false;
            for(int j=0; j<find.length; j++){
                if(find[j]==replace[counter])
                   charFound = true;
            }
    if(!charFound)
       replacedString.append(replace[counter]);
}

System.out.println("Replaced string" + replacedString.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Makes it a lot clearer, if I were to append extra letters to the new string builder would I just create another append to the replaced string or can I add it in the original append method? @GV

Comment: If I got it correctly, you want to find BC in ABCDE and replace it with XX ?